# Is BItcoin the only truly decentralized cryptocurrency?

Tags: altcoin, decentralization

Is Bitcoin (and likewise Bitcoin Cash)the only truly decentralized cryptocurrency? It appears that all the other altcoins are connected to companies or individuals who control them.

Comment: Litecoin for instance was a pretty early altcoin, and it is exactly the same basic design as Bitcoin, with minor changes.  I don't know how you'd describe it as "centralized".  There are lots more.

Answer (score 2):

There are many decentralized currencies, you can take a look here:

http://coinmarketcap.com/

Not all coins are connected to a company, the main big ones that are connected to a company are Ripple and Factom. Other coins might just have foundations that is responsible for marketing and other related matters, but they do not control the coin itself as the miners and coin holders do.